# Groups Of Rigid Motion

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Is the group of rigid motions ${G}$, the largest group of linear transformations in $F^n$ with composition as the product such that $<Av,Aw>=<v,w>$ where $A \in  {G}$ and $v,w \in F^n$ and $<,>$ denotes the inner product ?

If Yes, then is this also true for any vector space other than $F^n$ ?

If No, is it true for $R^n$ as the vector space ?

Or is ${G}$ a subset of a even larger group for both $F^n$ & $R^n$ as the vector spaces?

Comment: The condition $\langle Av, Bw\rangle = \langle v,w\rangle$ does not hold for translations, though.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan  Thank you, I have edited the question. I am currently learning this material.

Comment: If $\langle Av,Aw\rangle = \langle v,w\rangle$, then $A$ is automatically an isometry, so $G$ is, by definition, the largest such group.